# Integrity_Error (key is still referenced) thrown even with on_delete=do_nothing

Tags: django, orm

I have a model:

```
class Project(Model):
    name = models.TextField(...)
    ... bunch of fields ...
```

I also have some models that track history in my application. These models have `ForeignKey` references to the `Project` model:

```
class Historical_Milestone(Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', db_index=True, related_name='+',
                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I delete an item in my `Project` table, I get the following IntegrityError:

> update or delete on table "project" violates foreign key constraint {...} on table "historical_milestone"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(123) is still referenced from table "historical_milestone".

The column in the historical table has `related_name='+'` set (indicating that I don't want the reverse lookup), and I have the `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` parameter set. According to [the documentation on the DO_NOTHING option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#arguments):

> If your database backend enforces referential integrity, this will cause an IntegrityError unless you manually add an SQL ON DELETE constraint to the database field.

Shouldn't the `related_name` flag indicating I don't care about the reverse relationship take care of this? What manual step do I need to take to modify the Historical_Milestone table to prevent this error from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `related_name` is for convenience, it doesn't affect the foreign key constraints that Django creates. Setting `related_name='+'` simply means you don't want to be able to access `product.historical_milestone_set` (or similar) in the ORM.

If you want to keep the id after the project is deleted, and not enforce a foreign key constraint, it might be better to use an integer field.

```
class Historical_Milestone(Model):
    project_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? A simple fix. Thanks!